# Cookies detail - name and data

Tags: http, http-headers

when server responses with header Set-Cookie: ADS=SN=175A21EF. What does it mean? Do i have to save one cookie with name ADS containing data SN=175A21EF or are there two cookies ADS and SN containing data 175A21EF?

Thx for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs ([HTTP State Management Mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965), [HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), and the old RFC, superseded by 2965 - [rfc 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109)) it should be interpreted as "ADS" = "SN=175A21EF". There cannot be two cookies, a "Set-cookie" header can contain only one value and some another pre-defined key=value pairs separated by `;`.